# How do you turn off Visual Studio 2022's agressive new autocomplete behavior regarding curly braces?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I don't know what this feature is called, so I don't know how to turn it off.

Say you have some C++ code like the following

```
loc_map<int> find_distances(const grid& g, std::optional<int> n = -1) {
    //...
}
```

and the `n = -1` is a mistake because `n` had previously been an integer, not an optional integer, so you select `-1` and start typing `{}` because you want to replace `-1` with an empty optional. Currently Visual Studio makes this insane assumption that what you want to do is wrap the whole line in curly braces or something.

Briefly it seems as though with default editor settings in Visual Studio 2022 you can never *replace* text with curly braces without manually deleting the text first. How do I turn this off?